# Replacing backslash '\' in python

Tags: python, replace, python-unicode

When trying to replace '\' in python, the data changed and give me unknown letters.

i have tried string.replace, re.sub, regex_replace

```
a = '70\123456'
b = '70\123\456'

a = a.replace('\\','-')
b = b.replace('\\','-')
```

Expected Result:

```
a = '70-123456'
b = '70-123-456'
```

But The Actual Result is:

```
a = 70S456
b = 70SĮ
```

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I suggest you print `a` and `b` before calling `replace`

Comment: Try `print('70\123456')`. That string never contained a backslash to begin with…

Comment: Try to `print(a, b)` right after you define them. Do any of them have a backslash?

Comment: You should quote backslash not only in replace function.

Comment: See what `\ooo` means in a string literal: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22

Comment: In python strings, backslashes followed by numbers mean (sometimes) special characters, if you want to represent backslashes, you should double them (e.g: "\\") or use r"\"

Comment: They don't need to be special, e.g. `"\110\145\154\154\157\054\040\127\157\162\154\144\041"` is valid but not canonical. `repr` can frequently help.

Comment: thank your for your explanations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `\123` and `\456` are special characters(octal).
Try this:

```
a = r'70\123456'
b = r'70\123\456'

a = a.replace('\\','-')
b = b.replace('\\','-')

print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: i i want to make a script to concatenate 'r' with '70\123456'. 

from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws
n = concat_ws('r','70\123456')
print(n)


result: Column<b'concat_ws(r, 70S456)'>

Comment: @CharbelKeedy I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: my fields are coming as 70\123456 not as r'70\123456'. How to Handle it?

Comment: @CharbelKeedy what do you mean by fields are coming like this? If that's your literal wherever it comes from python handles it and parses it automatically to `70\\123456` from `70\123456`. It escapes the slash